# Equivalent Docker CMD for serving Flask application

Tags: python, docker, flask, command, dockerfile

I would like to know how can I properly use multiple arguments in CMD command in Dockerfile. I am using this command to run my server :-

`waitress-serve --port=9198 "final_1:app"`

Should I use this :-

```
EXPOSE 9198
CMD ["waitress-serve", "final_1:app"]
```

Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: yes that's how it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your images's startup point you can use `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions as per described in [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

In `ENTRYPOINT` you set the path for your application, and `CMD` you set the commands for this application.

`EXPOSE` is used to tell docker what ports do your container exposes for you to use `--publish` with.

So, in your case:

```
EXPOSE 9198
ENTRYPOINT ["waitress-serve"]
CMD ["--port=9198", "final_1:app"]
```

and in your command line to run the container, don't forget to add `--publish 9198:9198` to link the exposed container's port to the host port.

It is worth noting that this answer is simplification for docker's concepts viewed here, refer to the docs to know more about the uses for these instructions.

Comment: Please don't do this.  A common path to get a debugging shell for an image, for example,  is `docker run --rm -it imagename bash`.  Because of the way `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are combined, this runs `waitress-serve bash`, which will result in an error.  There's no reason to split out `ENTRYPOINT` this way; leave both parts in `CMD`.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Need to dig more about this point, but as general thought, with reference to the best practices and this [article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint), defining an `ENTRYPOINT` then `CMD` will help you modify your `CMD` in the command line and keeping the `ENTRYPOINT` which makes more sense, and override the `ENTRYPOINT` with `--entrypoint` when needed. Accessing bash for debug can be done through `docker exec -it container bash` which also more logical, as you access bash for debugging after the normal process of the container without overrides.